# Bottom App Navigator on FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the [persisten_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package to handle the bottom navigation in our app. The issue I'm having is that when I call `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` to get rid of the keyboard, the navigation bar goes dark for a second. Has anyone figure out how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code here? So we can replicate it on dartpad?

Answer (score 0):

So I implemented the package incorrectly, I fixed it by changing the parameters to the ones below. The main issue was `hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows` which was basically rendering the bottomAppBar every-time the keyboard closed.

```
PersistentTabView(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: false
```

**Tip**: Add resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false to any screens with textFields to prevent a small white spacing in between the keyboard and the scaffold

```
 Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```